# Decrypt AES encrypted image in browser using window.crypto.subtle.decrypt

Tags: openssl, aes, encryption-symmetric, subtlecrypto

**Business use-case:**

> In my application, i allow users to upload images. Now before storing
> it to file system, i want images to be aes-encrypted. For displaying
> images in browser, i want to decrypt them on the fly in browser. So
> basically they will be encrypted at rest, and will be decrypted at the
> time of playback.

**What i have implemented:**

> I have encrypted an image using open ssl and AES 265 CBC algorithm.
> Below is the command i used
>
> ```
> openssl enc -in image-original.jpg -out image-enc.jpg -e -aes256 -k 26ca44bbeb4b6608437737970cbfe0db
> ```
>
> On front-end, i send an HTTP call to server to read encrypted image as
> blob, and i try to decrypt that blob using
> window.crypto.subtle.decrypt function. Below is the code
>
> ```
> window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
>         {
>             name: "AES-CBC",
>             length: 256
>         },
>         "26ca44bbeb4b6608437737970cbfe0db",
>         "blob that we fetched from server"
>     ).then((result) => {
>         debugger;
>     });
> ```
>
> But i am getting below listed error in browser console
>
> ```
> "TypeError: Failed to execute 'decrypt' on 'SubtleCrypto': parameter 2 is not of type 'CryptoKey'."
> ```

**Questions:**

> I have 2 questions from you guys,
>
> 1. Help me resolve this error, as i am not finding much help over internet
> 2. Suggest me a better approach or share your experience if you have done such work in past.

Comment: The `-k` parameter in OpenSSL specifies a passphrase from which key and IV are derived, see [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html), and note also the `-p` / `-P` options. You may not use the passphrase in the Web Crypto code, but instead key and IV. OpenSSL also allows you to specify key and IV _directly_, maybe this makes more sense for you. The key used in the Web Crypto code is generally a `CryptoKey` object into which the _raw_ key is imported, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt).

Comment: @Topaco Your answer helped me alot in resolving this issue. I will be posting my complete solution here soon.

Comment: @AsadUllah, did you figure out how to fix this?

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs Instead of passing raw key to window.crypto.subtle.decrypt, I had to pass CryptoKey object into which raw key was imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the raw key, I had to pass [CryptoKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKey) object, in which the raw key was [imported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey).